# Why does "discard" button not show up right away?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've noticed just today that when I'm typing an answer, the "discard" button that should show up next to the "Post your answer" button doesn't appear right away.  It seems to appear later, but I haven't found a particular thing that causes it to happen, nor does it happen after a consistent time interval.

Is this the way the behavior has always been, and I just haven't noticed?  Is this a new feature?  Or just a bug?

Answer (score 4):

The discard button only appears when there is a draft to discard. Drafts are stored on the server, which doesn't happen immediately; it happens around [45 seconds in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238), though I've noticed it to be inconsistent as well.

This is how it's always been since the draft feature was introduced.

Comment: Then I guess I just never noticed before.  But before this feature was introduced, did the "discard" button show up right away, allowing me to discard my answer if I started typing something then thought better of it?  That's how I remember it, not that I trust my memory all that much, but if my memory is correct, then I don't see a reason why the behavior had to change.  It seems useful to be able to cancel whatever I started, even if I don't care about drafts.

Comment: @ajb: No, that button was introduced along with server-side drafts. It was never there before.

Comment: @ajb Prior to the draft being saved on the server there's nothing to 'discard'. To cancel what you've started typing, before a draft is saved, just refresh the page.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Your first sentence is wrong, in English terms.  If I've typed something in, and I want to get rid of it, then I want to discard it (that's what the word means).  So yes, there is something to discard.  I wasn't aware of the draft feature at all (why should I have been?), and the "discard" word made no reference to a draft, so it makes total sense that someone might see the button and think it was about discarding what they've already typed.